# Which propositional law shows that these propositions are equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$[¬p ∧ (r ∨ ¬q) ∨ [¬(¬p ∧ w)] ]   ≡  ¬p ∧ [(r ∨ ¬q) ∨ w]$$

I know that they are equivalent because I used a truth table to prove it. I also need to use a specific law to prove it, however.

Would de morgans law make sense for this problem? None of the other laws seem to apply to the equation.

Comment: the left hand side seems to be missing a right square bracket.

Comment: @Timkinsella you're right i fixed it

Comment: de Morgan's laws, and the distributive laws, seem like the way to go here

Comment: How do you parse $A\wedge B\vee C$? As $(A\wedge B)\vee C$, or as $A\wedge(B\vee C)$? While your right hand side is unambiguous, your left hand side is not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i didn't write the problem but i think the logical and has precedence over the logical or

Comment: I didn't ask who wrote the problem. I asked what rules you have to dispel the ambiguity.

Comment: The lefthand is written to be wrong.